# EJB bean or plain Managed Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Is this an EJB or ManagedBean? To be an EJB bean, must it be annotated by @stateful, @stateless or @Singleton? I thought @SessionScoped and @ApplicationScoped classes are also EJB beans. Is this right?

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("userData")
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UrlData data;

public UrlData getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(UrlData data) {
    this.data = data;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SessionScoped and @ApplicationScoped are part of ManagedBean not EJB, which classes as a resource with the JavaServer Faces.

- @ApplicationScoped: Application scope persists across all users’ interactions with a web application.
- @SessionScoped: Session scope persists across multiple HTTP requests in a web application.
- @ViewScoped: View scope persists during a user’s interaction with a single page (view) of a web application.
- @RequestScoped: Request scope persists during a single HTTP request in a web application.

You can see more detail in [Java-EE specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html)

This is an example code that inject EJB into ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Count {
    @EJB
    private CounterBean counterBean;

    private int hitCount;

    public Count() {
        this.hitCount = 0;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        hitCount = counterBean.getHits();
        return hitCount;
    }
    public void setHitCount(int newHits) {
        this.hitCount = newHits;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Many beans (including any "@SessionScoped" or "@ApplicationScoped" beans) are available for concurrent access. Therefore, the concurrency management provided by EJB 3.2 is especially useful. Most session and application scoped beans should be EJBs." I also saw this in a demo introducing JEE 7. Is that contradictory?

Comment: No, that description means the managedbean can access EJB by using @EJB annotation. You can inject one session bean(e.g. EJB, ManagedBean) into another session bean(), a managed bean into a session bean, a session bean into a managed bean and so on.

Comment: So to put it simply, only beans explicitly annotated with stateful, stateless or singleton are EJBs, otherwise, they are managed bean?

Comment: Yes, you can say like that.